# Buffer cycling in Emacs: avoiding scratch and Messages buffer

Tags: emacs

Hi I have turned on buffer cycling placing following commands in my .emacs

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'bury-buffer)
```

But while cycling how do I avoid cycling through the Messages and the scrratch buffers which
are always present in any emacs buffer list. I never use those buffers and become an eye-sore 
when cycling through my buffer-list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you never use the scratch buffer, just add this to your .emacs to automatically close it:

> (kill-buffer "*scratch*")

I also found [this code](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ControlTABbufferCycling#toc3) on the [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/) which should do what you want:

```
; necessary support function for buffer burial
(defun crs-delete-these (delete-these from-this-list)
  "Delete DELETE-THESE FROM-THIS-LIST."
  (cond
   ((car delete-these)
    (if (member (car delete-these) from-this-list)
        (crs-delete-these (cdr delete-these) (delete (car delete-these)
                                                 from-this-list))
      (crs-delete-these (cdr delete-these) from-this-list)))
   (t from-this-list)))
; this is the list of buffers I never want to see
(defvar crs-hated-buffers
  '("KILL" "*Compile-Log*"))
; might as well use this for both
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore (append '("^ " "*Buffer") crs-hated-buffers))
(defun crs-hated-buffers ()
  "List of buffers I never want to see, converted from names to buffers."
  (delete nil
          (append
           (mapcar 'get-buffer crs-hated-buffers)
           (mapcar (lambda (this-buffer)
                     (if (string-match "^ " (buffer-name this-buffer))
                         this-buffer))
                   (buffer-list)))))
; I'm sick of switching buffers only to find KILL right in front of me
(defun crs-bury-buffer (&optional n)
  (interactive)
  (unless n
    (setq n 1))
  (let ((my-buffer-list (crs-delete-these (crs-hated-buffers)
                                          (buffer-list (selected-frame)))))
    (switch-to-buffer
     (if (< n 0)
         (nth (+ (length my-buffer-list) n)
              my-buffer-list)
       (bury-buffer)
       (nth n my-buffer-list)))))
(global-set-key [(control tab)] 'crs-bury-buffer)
(global-set-key [(control meta tab)] (lambda ()
                                       (interactive)
                                       (crs-bury-buffer -1)))
```

You will need to add the scratch and message buffers to the variable `crs-hated-buffers`, e.g.:

```
(add-to-list 'crs-hated-buffers "*Messages*")
(add-to-list 'crs-hated-buffers "*scratch*")
```

Answer (score 5):

Luke's answered your specific question.  In my personal experience buffer cycling is more useful as a most-recently-used stack instead of the Emacs default cycling functions.  That is, the buffers you most recently used should bubble to the top of the stack, similar to how alt-tab works in Windows.

There are quite a few packages that implement this on the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ControlTABbufferCycling#toc1).  `buffer-stack` is the one I recommend.  It has a list of excluded buffers by default, I've included my `buffer-stack-suppl` configuration, which does same major-mode filtering.  If you ask questions about `buffer-stack`, I'll try my best to help.

Comment: How do I specify a wildcard when I ask buffer-stack to always ignore/untrack certain buffers? e.g. if I want to ask it to add to untrack list *.html how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

All the buffers I did not use, such as scratch, messages and completions, messed with my workflow.

I've managed to completely get rid of them, without breaking emacs in any way.

Posted first [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152151/72170), and pasted bellow:

Place this in your .emacs:

```
;; Makes *scratch* empty.
(setq initial-scratch-message "")

;; Removes *scratch* from buffer after the mode has been set.
(defun remove-scratch-buffer ()
  (if (get-buffer "*scratch*")
      (kill-buffer "*scratch*")))
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'remove-scratch-buffer)

;; Removes *messages* from the buffer.
(setq-default message-log-max nil)
(kill-buffer "*Messages*")

;; Removes *Completions* from buffer after you've opened a file.
(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (let ((buffer "*Completions*"))
           (and (get-buffer buffer)
                (kill-buffer buffer)))))

;; Don't show *Buffer list* when opening multiple files at the same time.
(setq inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)

;; Show only one active window when opening multiple files at the same time.
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'delete-other-windows)
```

Bonus:

```
;; No more typing the whole yes or no. Just y or n will do.
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use `ido-mode` to cycle between buffers you can set `ido-ignore-buffers` to match the buffers you want to ignore. From the documentation:

> List of regexps or functions matching buffer names to ignore. 
>   For example, traditional behavior is not to list buffers whose names begin
>   with a space, for which the regexp is "` ".  See the source file for 
>   example functions that filter buffer names.

For more info on `ido-mode` see: [Introduction to ido-mode](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/10/introduction-to-ido-mode/)