# How to hide emacs buffers (for good)

Tags: emacs

I want to prevent emacs from bothering me with unwanted buffers. I've set `ido-ignore-buffers`
appropriately and this works well to keep them from appearing in the buffer list when I `C-x b`. However, these buffers are still cycled through when i use `next-buffer` and `previous-buffer`. Even more annoyingly this makes them even appear in the buffer list afterwards. How do I make previous/next-buffer ignore them altogether?

Comment: I'm not current with emacs functions because I've set up most what I need at the end of the last millennium and didn't have much trouble since. What you always can do is write new functions my-next-buffer and my-previous buffer and bind them to keys of your liking.

Comment: This ignores all buffers whose name starts with blanks: (defun exhume-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((bl (buffer-list)) (ex (car (last bl))))
    (while (and bl (string= (substring (buffer-name ex) 0 1) " "))
      (setq bl (butlast bl) ex (car (last bl))))
    (switch-to-buffer ex)
    ))

Comment: It lacks votes, but I'll suggest you at least take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24840977/324105) to the duplicate question.